# Does using libraries to implement a service defy SOA principles?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, soa

We are developing multiple web services in C# using WCF, but we´re new doing it.

So, for what we have read and learnt, this is our approach:

- We have a class library that we called `CommonLibrary` that has a few classes that are going to be used on all our services (language stuff, type of user connected and a common object that all the services are meant to return).
- We have another class library called `SecurityLibrary` which validates the user that is consuming the method.
- At the moment we have 2 services that are almost at 90% finished, both of them use `CommonLibrary` and `SecurityLibrary`.

Now the questions:

- Is this a bad approach?
- Are we violating the SOA principles of encapsulation and autonomy by using common/shared library with each of our services?
- A third person told us to copy all the code of those libraries on each of our services so we have a 100% autonomous service, is this the right way? I think is hard for maintenance and shows a lot of duplicity. Any update made on one has to be replicated or merged on those other services...

Comment: This type of questions is probably more appropriate for Code Review or Programmers, as these are more design/philosophy questions.

Comment: This is offtopic for SO and bordering on opinion-based, but "SOA" means just that: **service** oriented architecture. Whether you use libraries to build that service is entirely irrelevant to the SOA part; that person telling you to copy all library code into your service project doesn't know what they're talking about.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks for your reply, I know that the comment of the person was shocking, but how can I reply that, I mean, I can't find a place were I can tell him this is wrong or this is bad, I don't get why is opinion-based, should SOA follow some principles?

Comment: @CodeCaster Basically, I need to tell him what he is suggesting is wrong for the reasons I put on my question, but I need more bases that those, that's why I come for help, I don't think it is a subjective question.

Comment: Why the down vote? I cannot see why this is not an objective and valid question, and if it is, then the answer must be really easy... Thanks

Comment: Try on programmers.se as answering it will require more than a few sentences. Anyway: code reuse is good, and using libraries (assemblies) for that is the accepted common practice for that. If that person wants to derive from that by copying code instead, _they_ have to defend why they'd want to do that.

Comment: @CodeCaster those are very strong reasons, I'll go with that for the moment. If you have time to elaborate an answer even more I'll appreciated it a lot. I know that his answer will be: "but it still violates the SOA principles", I think I can call him a purist. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Nowhere does it say _"A SOA project must be self-contained and not contain third-party or library code"_. Let them find a source for that - they won't be able to find that.

Comment: The person is obviously confused by the tenet "Services are autonomous" in the tenets of SOA, and the meaning of the word autonomous in this case. Autonomy does not imply physical separation at design-time.

Comment: @SamIam and other reopen-voters: what makes this question ontopic?

Comment: @TomRedfern I agree, in fact, I've been talking to this person and he mantains his position about "a SOA web service must be completely aislated or we are doing it wrong, we need to replicate code on each service, we cannot shared classes or assemblies"...

Comment: Voted to close again/deleted "answer" - as main point of the question is about discussing personal opinion what "autonomous" means.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I don't agree with your comment, it's not a personal opinion, it's about clarifying a bad interpretation, I'm trying to understand as much as possible if I'm doing web services implementing SOA the right way. There **must** be a right way of doing it, not a: "I think I'm doing it well" (which is personal opinion based), it has to be objective.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not a bad approach?

If using libaries in your service, you should also keep away from the .NET-library. I am wonding why you are thinking that a service process is only allowed to exist of only one assembly.

Furthermore, copy-paste code is a very, very bad habbit. It is known as a anti-design-pattern. I duplicates the maintainance and also all the bugs inside it.

Sharing libaries does not make your service less "autonomous". I think it could make them more compatible if they are sharing types.

A good service is just a process, existing of one or more (shared) assemblies, with a well defined service contract. This service contract is never allowed to be broken.

BTW: In my answer I did not include problems which shared assemblies in the GAC. That is a feature or problem shared by all processes, not only services.